# Tutorial on Linked Lists

Tags: linked-list

I know google delivers so many tutorials when i search `"Linked List Tutorials"` in it. But the best and concise tutorial among them, i am sure `Stackoverflow` will know. So guide me to those tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/ is a basic tutorial describing the essence of linked lists in very much detail.